# timer/promises.setTimeout delay not working with function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node v16 and it looks like what I was previously doing in Node v13 doesn't work anymore due to this additional import statement? I am trying to delay calling this function for 1 minute, however when I run this it seems to call the function immediately over and over again or never execute. How do I get back to my 1 minute delay? I tried all of the below:

`setTimeout((1 * 60 * 1000), doSomething());`

`setTimeout(doSomething(), (1 * 60 * 1000));`

`setTimeout(() => { doSomething() }, 1 * 60 * 1000);`  (this one never executed at all)

`setTimeout(doSomething, (1 * 60 * 1000));`  (this one never executed at all)

Note I am also using an import statement here for Node v16:

`const { setTimeout, } = require('timers/promises');`

and calling just `await setTimeout(4000);` seems to work alright because of that

I'm sure that this is because timers/promises.setTimeout is different than setTimeout, but I don't understand how to use both in the code?

I want to be able to use both of these things within my script at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both:

```js
const { setTimeout: setTimeoutPromiseBased } = require('timers/promises');

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Hello, traditional world');
}, 1000);
(async function() {
  await setTimeoutPromiseBased(2000);
  console.log('Hello, promisified world');
})();
```

The above uses the aliasing syntax for destructuring. Otherwise, you'd end up overwriting the global "setTimeout" with the promise-enabled version.

Comment: I see! I will ned to do more research on that. Thank you so much, this works!

Answer (score 0):

With your current import, you are replacing the default setTimeout with the [Timer Promises setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timerspromises_settimeout_delay_value_options), which only accepts a delay.

If you would like to use both, I suggest changing your import to something like

```js
const tp = require('timers/promises');
```

and then reference Timers Promises `setTimeout` like so:

```js
tp.setTimeout(4000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for setTimeout is: `setTimeout(function, number in milliseconds)`.

So if you want to call a function after 1 minute, you need to do:

```
setTimeout(doSomething, 60000)
```

You shouldn't use `doSomething()` (note the parantheses), otherwise the function is called immediately

Comment: OP is using the `timers/promises` `setTimeout` which has a different interface than that used in the browser: https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timerspromisessettimeoutdelay-value-options